# Incompatible types: 'PPointerList' and 'TPointerList' in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

I am getting error `Incompatible types: 'PPointerList' and 'TPointerList'` in following function.

```
function MyFunction: PPointerList;
begin
  result := FList.List;
end;
```

FList.List return TPointerList type. This code is working fine in Delphi 7 code but throwing error in Delphi XE4.

PPointerList and TPointerList are declared in System.Classes

In System.Classes

```
PPointerList = ^TPointerList;
TPointerList = array of Pointer;
```

When I typecasted TPointerList to PPointerList, it worked like

```
function MyFunction: PPointerList;
begin
  result := PPointerList(FList.List);
end;
```

Is it the right solution, or what should I do to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TList` has changed. The internal field `FList` used to be `PPointerList` but it's now `TPointerList`. To return a pointer to it, you can use this:

```
function MyFunction: PPointerList;
begin
  Result := @FList.List;
end;
```

Comment: TOndrej and TLama - Thanks for you help. It resolved my problem.